# Remove leading zeros from multiple numbers in string? [C++]

Tags: c++, regex, string, formatting

Let's say I have a string that contains "00001234 00002345", but I want to output it at "1234 2345". How would I go about that?

```
    str.erase(0, str.find_first_not_of('0'));
```

This removes the 0's from the first number, but not any preceding number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `\b0+` regex (it matches `0` symbols after a non-word character, i.e. `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`) if you are interested in a regex solution:

```
std::string input("00001234 00002345");
std::regex rgx(R"(\b0+)");
std::cout << std::regex_replace(input, rgx, "");
// => 1234 2345
```

See [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/q8Ctw9)

Note that raw string literals allow us to use single backslashes to escape regex metacharacters.